# Как добавить звук и картинки на сайт

Tags: javascript

У меня есть тренажер для изучения языков https://www.trenajor.me. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь выбирает песню, смог бы, например нажав на правую клавишу, услышать звучание слов. Я думаю, что я мог бы иметь базу данных со звучанием, просто подключить ее и к каждому слову привязать звучание из базы и проигрывать. Где взять такую базу? Я написал в [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) и они радостно высылают прайс с годовым пользованием русско-английской базой в 5200к американских за годовое пользование. Это очень дорого. Может быть есть где-то и дешевле? А возможно например написать какой-то бот или код, чтобы по нажатию робот заходил на сайт, вбивал в поиск данное слово и происходило звучание?

То же самое с картинками. Чтобы нажимая на кнопку открывалось окно и появлялось отображение этого слова с гугл картинок.

Comment: <button onclick="window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello world'))"> проговорить "hello world"  </button>

Comment: Олег!! А если текст формирует сам пользователь и ты не знаешь на какое слово он нажмет?

Comment: т. е., имеется текст, и при клике на одно любое слово это слово оно должно прозвучать? В таком плане?

Comment: зайдите в тренажер trenajor.me вставьте в левое поле текст песни, нажмите Go появится новая страница. В ней пользователь отгадывает. он отгадал слово, но не знает что оно означает.Он выделил его и нажал к примеру ctrl+M и появляется его звучание ctrl +T - перевод ctrl + P - картинка.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Допустим, это текст, который появляется на второй странице тренажора.<br />
Выделяем любое слово и жмём <b>ctr + m</b> для проговаривания.
<script>
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 77){
        var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(window.getSelection());
        synth.speak(utterance);
    }
}
</script>
```